# What are all the ways to get the Stop 'n Swop items in Banjo-Kazooie?

Tags: nintendo-64, banjo-kazooie

I know that the Stop 'n Swop items were never able to be used for their intended purpose. If they had worked out, it would have made for some really cool features.

Anyway, I'm curious about how to get to them. Can all (or any) of them be obtained *without* hacking? For example, the only way I know of to get the Ice Key is to have a levitate code on to fly over the wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of rhyming codes you can enter into the floor of Treasure Trove Cove's sandcastle that unlock the areas for those items, although I don't know what they are off the top of my head (and most gaming sites are blocked where I work).

Alternatively, you can play the Xbox Live Arcade release, which does implement Stop 'n Swop with Banjo-Tooie's XBLA release.  The items are collectible after you defeat Gruntilda.

(Edit) You may need either a Banjo-Kazooie: Nuts & Bolts save or Banjo-Tooie on the same 360 to access the Stop 'n Swop items.

Side Note: Banjo-Tooie's XBLA release had a Stop 'n Swop II, the purpose of which isn't actually clear since it doesn't appear to integrate with Banjo-Kazooie: Nuts & Bolts.

(Edit) New Stop 'n Swop II items (eggs?) replaced the eggs and Ice Key in BT, which are now only available in BK.

(Edit 2)
And now, finally, here are the Treasure Trove Cove codes to open the secret items:

First, enter the code CHEAT.

To remove the ice wall in Freezyeasy Peak for the Ice Key, enter:
NOW YOU CAN SEE A NICE ICE KEY WHICH YOU CAN HAVE FOR FREE

To open the door in Gobi's Valley which has the Blue Egg behind it, enter:
A DESERT DOOR OPENS WIDE ANCIENT SECRETS WAIT INSIDE

To make Sharkfood Island rise in Treasure Trove Cove for the Purple Egg, enter:
OUT OF THE SEA IT RISES TO REVEAL MORE SECRET PRIZES

To open the X-marked Cask in the cellar of Mad Monster Mansion for the Cyan Egg, enter:
DONT YOU GO AND TELL HER ABOUT THE SECRET IN HER CELLAR

In Mad Monster Mansion, you can find the Green Egg in Loggo's bathroom if you enter:
AMIDST THE HAUNTED GLOOM A SECRET IN THE BATHROOM

Click Clock Wood has the Yellow Egg in Nabnut's house if you enter:
NOW BANJO WILL BE ABLE TO SEE IT ON NABNUTS TABLE

Rusty Bucket Bay is hiding the Red Egg in the Captain's Room if you enter:
THIS SECRET YOULL BE GRABBIN IN THE CAPTAINS CABIN
(Note that you have to enter said cabin from one of the windows, in case you've forgotten.)

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa - they made the S&S items useful on XBLA? This is news to me.

Comment: @Corey: Yes, they did! You may have to own either Banjo-Tooie or Banjo-Kazooie: Nuts & Bolts to access them, though.  Also, they removed the existing eggs and Ice Key from BT; you must gather them in BK.  Having said that, the eggs now give you various bonuses, such as art, rather than being used for game stuff.  The Ice Key is still needed to get the Mega-Glowbo, though.

Comment: There, I added all the cheat codes now.

Comment: They get you special vehicle parts in *Banjo Kazooie: Nuts n Bolts* too.